# EditorInfo always returns empty mime-type array

Tags: android, keyboard

EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo); always returning empty suppoeted mime types array.I debuged in google messenger app and the  demo commitcontent  support app provided by google. this bellow code snippet  always returning false.Please help!

```
final String[] supportedMimeTypes = EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo);
    for (String supportedMimeType : supportedMimeTypes) {
        if (ClipDescription.compareMimeTypes(mimeType, supportedMimeType)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
 return false;
```